# ISNULL function in SQL Server 2008 not working properly

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Assume this script:

```
DECLARE @result TABLE(Id BIGINT);

DELETE FROM [Products].[Product]
OUTPUT DELETED.[Id] INTO @result
WHERE [Products].[Product].[Id] = 1589;
```

So in continues I try :

**1**

```
SELECT CAST(ISNULL([Id], -1) AS BIGINT) AS N'RetValId' FROM @result;
```

When `[Id]` is null returned null (nothing), but this one returned -1:

**2**

```
DECLARE @mi BIGINT;
SET @mi = (SELECT [Id] FROM @result)
SELECT CAST(ISNULL(@mi, -1) AS BIGINT) AS N'RetValId'
```

Why? where is the problem with first script?

**Update**

So is there any way to check if the Deleted Id is null returned -1 And if not Returned Id without declare another variable? what is the simplest way?

Comment: If your first script doesn't actually delete anything, DELETED will contain no rows. ISNULL won't be called. In the second example, because you are doing a subselect, ISNULL will actually be called.

Comment: @marc_s I don't have any `Product` whit Id = 1589, So nothing deleted and nothing inserted into @result, then I expect first script mean this: (`SELECT CAST(ISNULL([Id], -1) AS BIGINT) AS N'RetValId' FROM @result;`) returned -1 but nothing returned, why? and why the second one returned -1

Comment: @marc_s look this one http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d489/1

Comment: That's exactly the point : if the table contains no rows, then the `SELECT` will return no rows, therefore `ISNULL` cannot be applied to a column - since it's not there.

Comment: I updated your sqlfiddle.
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0d489/2  

Here is the MAX([ID]) solution you can check how it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you have no entry for the ID 1589, then in the DELETED table there will be no record, if you have it then it should return 1589.

So if you don't have I think it simple returns nothing, because this statement has no input row:

```
SELECT CAST(ISNULL([Id], -1) AS BIGINT) AS N'RetValId' FROM @result;
```

(If you SELECT * from @result it should be no rows there)

The second one return the -1 because you set first to the variable which is getting the NULL value after the select.

```
DECLARE @mi BIGINT;
SET @mi = (SELECT [Id] FROM @result)
```

(If you select only @mi after this, then it should be NULL)

I think that is the explanation

UPDATED:

May you can try a small trick to achive it without an other varriable:

```
SELECT CAST(ISNULL(MAX([ID]),-1) AS BIGINT) AS N'RetValId' FROM @result;
```

Because of MAX the insie statement will be NULL, so here is the trick. If something was deleted, then the ID will be there. 
I hope it helped.

Comment: Thanks, So is there any way to check if the Deleted Id is null returned -1 And if not Returned Id without declare another variable? what is the simplest way?

Comment: Yes you can write IF SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM @result = 0 BEGIN SELECT -1 END ELSE BEGIN ..... END . It is also a solution, just a bit longer, but working too sure.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a derived table that will return one row with `-1` and then do an `outer apply` on `@result`.

```
select isnull(R.Id, T.Id) RetValId
from (values(-1)) as T(Id)
  outer apply @result as R
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to return `null` if no rows where deleted is the `@@rowcount` variable.  It contains the number of rows affected by the previous operation:

```
DELETE FROM [Products].[Product]
WHERE [Products].[Product].[Id] = 1589;

IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0
    return null
return 1589
```